# quadratic equation: $5x^2 + 9x - 170 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have a problem, my textbook says the solution of $5x^2 + 9x - 170 = 0$ is $5$ but the book didn't describe how it solved the equation.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the quadratic formula?

Comment: Somehow, I know how to make complete square, b^2 - 4ac and factoring but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the quadratic formula $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-9\pm\sqrt{9^2-4\cdot{5}\cdot{(-170)}}}{2\cdot{5}}=\frac{-9\pm\sqrt{3481}}{10}$$
Please continue.

Answer (score 5):

- **Hint.** $5x^{2} +9x -170 = 5x^{2} -25x + 34x + 170$

Answer (score 2):

for the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ we have $\displaystyle x_{1,2}=-\frac{b}{2a}\pm\frac{1}{2a}\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$

Answer (score 1):

Just complete the square:
$$
5x^2+9x−170=0\\
25x^2+45x−850=0\\
100x^2+180x−3400=0\\
(10x + 9)^2 - 3481=0
$$
Now as $3481 = 59^2$ this is equivalent to
$$
10x + 9 = \pm 59\\
x = 5 \text{ or } x = -6.8
$$